# In MySQL is there a way or command to say point to a file where the images are stored?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a database for a company.  They want a MySQL database and they want to store images for over 11,000 products.  I just wanted to know if there is a way or command to say point to a file where the images are stored.

Comment: Do they want to store images in the DB or just urls to locate them?

Comment: I am sorry I was asking which way was better

Comment: Nickhar I was looking for code for urls to locate them

Comment: No problem - looks like you have your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save at as a `VARCHAR`, and that value represents a path to that file.  Then just do:

```
$q=mysql_query("select path from images where id=123");
if($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo '<img src="'.$r['path'].'">';
}
```

Regarding the other option, you *can* store images as BLOBs in mysql, but then you have to go through mysql to get it.  And you'll have write a script that will send an image to the browser.  I think it's much better to keep them on the filesystem, and just use mysql to point to them.  Then when an  tag is sent to the browser, your webserver will handle the serving of that image correctly for you.  Also, if you have shell/ftp access to your server, it will make managing/viewing your images a lot easier and simple.

Comment: Landon thank you the MYSQL\PHP knowledge I have is limited at best would this work on MySQL workbench?

Comment: Landon it is an oracle program that I downloaded to make the table with, also not enough reputation or I would give you one

Comment: It is more of a GUI interface is a nicer way of saying it

Comment: Landon Check it out if you want to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench or mysqlworkbench.org

Answer (score 0):

You can store the files in table columns with the `blob` datatype.
Either that, or store the server file path in a string(`varchar`) field, and retrieve files using server code, after reading from the database.

Comment: Vinod thank you for your response retrieve files using server code is the way I would want to go with the blob thing I tried and it seems like it would be a pain to do that for 11,000+ images I was asking for an example of the code used to retrieve files

Comment: That depends on the server-side technology. For example, in a .NET server, you can write C# code to do this.

Image.ReadFromFile("filePath");

You can then write this image onto a virtual directory and display on a webpage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx

Comment: Vinod thanks again I am in a .Net server I will try C# code I appreciate your help

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts, if the files are stored on the server, you don't really have to read/write at all. You just need to convert the physical path to a virtual path to render onto a web page.
(Physical path might be like: `C:\Images\` while the virtual path would start with an ip address)
Very easy!